# Spacing between Font Awesome icons

Tags: font-awesome

How can I set spacing between icons that appear in line? Here's my code:

```
<p>
  <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-2x"></i>
</p>
```

The icons are too close to each other for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just set a margin as you would do for anything else. Pure CSS.

Answer (score 26):

use the `fa-fw` class:

https://origin.fontawesome.com/docs/web/style/fixed-width

It's clean, and better than adding a style to your elements.

(Updated link - thanks Paul)

Comment: Link in answer is dead, here's some info https://origin.fontawesome.com/docs/web/style/fixed-width

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can use `&nbsp;` to create a space

```
<i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers mention the `fa-fw` class, which works well for a lot of scenarios. However, there are some cases where this is not enough spacing.

For those who use Bootstrap, use `me-` (margin-right) or `ms-` (margin-left) classes to specify which side and how much margin.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Fontsawesome CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <title>Bootstrap 5.0 Fontsawesome Margin Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>No Margin</h1>
  <p>
    <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-google-plus"></i>
  </p>

  <h1>ME-1</h1>
  <p>
    <i class="fab fa-facebook me-1"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-twitter me-1"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-google-plus me-1"></i>
  </p>

  <h1>ME-2</h1>
  <p>
    <i class="fab fa-facebook me-2"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-twitter me-2"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-google-plus me-2"></i>
  </p>

  <h1>ME-3</h1>
  <p>
    <i class="fab fa-facebook me-3"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-twitter me-3"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-google-plus me-3"></i>
  </p>

  <h1>ME-4</h1>
  <p>
    <i class="fab fa-facebook me-4"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-twitter me-4"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-google-plus me-4"></i>
  </p>

  <h1>ME-5</h1>
  <p>
    <i class="fab fa-facebook me-5"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-twitter me-5"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-google-plus me-5"></i>
  </p>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-j0CNLUeiqtyaRmlzUHCPZ+Gy5fQu0dQ6eZ/xAww941Ai1SxSY+0EQqNXNE6DZiVc"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding

Comment: me-0 is nice when a button only has an icon.